# Probability of a result when spinning a disk

Tags: probability

A circular disk is divided into $5$ equal segments. On spinning the disk a pointer always points to one segment. The segments contain pictures of $2$ bananas, $2$ lemons and one kiwi fruit. The disk is spun $4$ times.

The probability of not getting a kiwi is $\frac45 \times \frac45 \times \frac45 \times \frac45  = 0.410$.

The probability of getting one kiwi is $(\frac15 \times \frac45 \times \frac45 \times \frac45)  + (\frac15 \times \frac45 \times \frac45 \times \frac45) + (\frac15 \times \frac45 \times \frac45 \times \frac45) + (\frac15 \times \frac45 \times \frac45 \times \frac45) = 0.410$

What is wrong here? the probability of no kiwi or one kiwi cannot be the same?

Comment: Nothing is wrong here, the probabilities are the same and you are correct.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I finally see it, even though it is a strange result! I suppose its an example of letting the numbers speak for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer to allow the question to be answered:

As cr001 pointed out in a comment, nothing is wrong, the proabilities are the same and you are correct.